# Menu position relative to document height with media query

Tags: javascript, css

I modify the css of the menu with javascript. I try to avoid from "overflow: scroll".

1. "position: fixed" for menu when its content height is less than document height.
2. Else I set "position: absolute" and set height as document height. It works as how I want.

Is it possible to do this only with @media queries? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't check the height of your content with CSS. You would be able to make a breakpoint, if you can give a number height where you want to switch, but you can't compare your content heigh and document height.

```
div{
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
}
@media (max-height: 300px){ //Has to be a set number
  position: fixed;
  height: 300px;
}
```

See, it would need to be a fixed number.

Comment: Thanks, than the only answer would be javascript for me because the height of the menu is not in my control.